# In a multithreaded app, can 2+ threads access the same function if the function does not modify/read data or modifies/reads temporary data?

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, c++11, mutex

I can't seem to find an answer anywhere on Google. I basically want to know if 2 threads can access normal/member functions like these at the same time and not result in undefined behavior or do I have to use a mutex?

```
void foo(void)
{
  float x(133.7);
  float y(10);
  std::cout << std::endl << (x * y);
}

void foobar(void)
{
  std::cout << std::endl << 1/1;
}
```

Comment: Not being a c++ dev I will not provide an official answer, but you can call these functions on multiple threads without locking with no problems. The variables are allocated on private stack memory of the threads so not shared (they are also not mutated), and the standard functions being called are thread-safe AFAIK. There is nothing that can be seen\mutated by multiple threads (in your code), so no locking is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure your code doesn't have undefined behaviour.

That said, you **are** using shared data, namely `std::cout`.

So if you expect `std::cout << std::endl << (x * y)` to be executed as a single operation (e.g. to prevent bits of output from different threads getting interleaved on stdout), you are going to have to use locks.

Comment: +1 Whilst the individual std functions are thread-safe, as there are multiple function calls, the output may be interleaved. Well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

> I basically want to know if 2 threads can access normal/member functions like these at the same time and not result in undefined behavior or do I have to use a mutex?

Yes.  You only need the synchronization if the threads will be using shared data.  Synchronization is more about protecting the state, not the code itself.